Spring Data Jpa save calls getId which returns null
I am struggling to find a reason why the save method calls the getId method when the id should be auto generated.
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMLTPLP")
public class EmlTplp {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emltplid")
    private Long id;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // other methods
}


@Service
public class EmailTemplateRepository {
    @Autowired private DBEmailTemplateRepo repo;

    public void save(EmlTplp item) {
        repo.save(item);
    }

    // other methods
}

@Repository interface DBEmailTemplateRepo extends JpaRepository<EmlTplp, Long> {
    EmlTplp findById(long id);
    List<EmlTplp> findAllByOrderByTitle();
}

When I call save it throws a NPE because getId() has returned null (I debugged it to that point). It is indeed null but I can't think why it is calling getId having annotated id as generated.
Any clues much appreciated. MAW

I have solved this now. It came down to simply changing the return type of getId() from long to Long. I did some debugging through the CRUD save() method and found it was trying to find out if this was a new entity (which it clearly was in this case). It was fine when returning a Long that was null, but got a TargetInvocationException when returning null when the return type was long.
